# How to get synonym for multiple word using NLTK?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I have searched that all questions only provide the way to get synonym for one word, but it doesn't work when I try to use a for loop to get synonym for multiple words.

This is my code, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
str = "Action, Adventure, Drama"

def process_genre(str):
    for genre in str.split(","):
        result = []
        for syn in wordnet.synsets(genre):
            for l in syn.lemmas():
                result.append(l.name())
        print(result)
process_genre(str)
```

This is the output

```
['action', 'action', 'activity', 'activeness', 'military_action', 'action', 'natural_process', 'natural_action', 'action', 'activity', 'action', 'action', 'action', 'action_mechanism', 'legal_action', 'action', 'action_at_law', 'action', 'action', 'action', 'sue', 'litigate', 'process', 'carry_through', 'accomplish', 'execute', 'carry_out', 'action', 'fulfill', 'fulfil']
[]
[]
```

The list for `Adventure` and `Drama` prints empty, which is supposed to have its synonym.

Can anyone explain to me why? Is there a way to maybe reset it? Or...?

Comment: Free tip: Don't use `str` as a variable name. It is the name of the string type, and you are setting yourself up for puzzling problems in the future if you get in the habit of using it as a variable. Python does permit it (it's not a reserved keyword like `if`), but discourages it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think issue is with your input.
You have extra space after `,` so when you split on `,` your words become `["Action", " Adventure"," Drama"]`

In wordnet there are no such words as `Adventure` and `Drama` (Notice a blank space at the start of word). This is why you are not getting output for 2nd and 3rd word.

**Work around for your input**

split on `", "` instead of `","`

```
str = "Action, Adventure, Drama"

def process_genre(str):
    for genre in str.split(", "):
        result = []
        for syn in wordnet.synsets(genre):
            for l in syn.lemmas():
                result.append(l.name())
        print(result)
process_genre(str)
```

Output:

```
['action', 'action', 'activity', 'activeness', 'military_action', 'action', 'natural_process', 'natural_action', 'action', 'activity', 'action', 'action', 'action', 'action_mechanism', 'legal_action', 'action', 'action_at_law', 'action', 'action', 'action', 'sue', 'litigate', 'process', 'carry_through', 'accomplish', 'execute', 'carry_out', 'action', 'fulfill', 'fulfil']
['adventure', 'escapade', 'risky_venture', 'dangerous_undertaking', 'gamble', 'chance', 'risk', 'hazard', 'take_chances', 'adventure', 'run_a_risk', 'take_a_chance', 'venture', 'hazard', 'adventure', 'stake', 'jeopardize']
['play', 'drama', 'dramatic_play', 'drama', 'dramatic_event', 'drama', 'drama']
```

Comment: Oh, right. I should just do the strip after the split. silly mistake to me :/ Thanks for the help!

Comment: I recommend getting into the habit of separating your strings of terms with spaces, not comma+space. Makes life easier and is less error-prone. And then you can just split with `terms.split()`.